# python raise exception inside a variable

Tags: python

Is it possible to raise an exception inside a variable?

What is the best practice of doing something like this?

```
side = side.lower() if side in 'left right'.split() else raise Exception(' wrong side!')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, nor would there be *any point*. You cannot assign the result of a `raise` to a variable.

Since you are raising an exception and the variable will never be bound **anyway**, you should just use a `if` statement to raise the exception, then assign:

```
if side.lower() not in ('left', 'right'):
    raise Exception('wrong side!')
side = side.lower()
```

If `side` is a local variable it won't matter if you assigned to it or not, as the exception raised will exit the scope anyway, so you can also reverse the statements to avoid calling `str.lower()` twice:

```
side = side.lower()
if side not in ('left', 'right'):
    raise Exception('wrong side!')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about separating user input from program values?

This is what I mean:

```
LEFT, RIGHT = -1, 1 # they can be any two values

valid_sides = {"left": LEFT, "right": RIGHT}

side = valid_sides[side.lower()]
```

This will raise an exception for invalid inputs **and** de-couple input from in-program value.

If you could use the strings themselves better, no problem:

```
LEFT, RIGHT = "left", "right"
```

So `LEFT` and `RIGHT` can be any pair of different values, and this code is more maintainable.

You could also make more inputs available for the same in-program value:

```
# including hebrew (left==smol, right==yemin)
valid_sides = {
    "left": LEFT, "smol": LEFT, "right": RIGHT, "yemin": RIGHT
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want, you can **assign** `Exception` to a variable, but that's not raising. It could have sense, if you're doing some global exception handling, but I can't imagine how you might use it.
E.g. you could do something like below:

```
side = side.lower() if side in 'left right'.split() else ValueException(' wrong side!')
#in other place that uses side
if isinstance(side, Exception):
    #silent fail
else:
    #do something useful here
```

but in other place that can't just silently fail:

```
if isinstance(side, Exception):
    raise side
```

I'm not sure if you should do it that way, for me that's strange way of error handling. I'd rather create container for errors, in case I'm doing lot of silent fails, and store there whole tracebacks.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice to check something works or not and raise an exception in case of failure is to put them in a function/method and use that in the code. Like this:

```
def validate_side(direction):
    if direction in ('left', 'right'):
        return direction.lower()
    else:
        raise Exception('Wrong side!!')
```

And then calling `validate_side` for your variables. The reason you want the exception in a variable is that you don't want something to break the flow and in the end you end up cleaning things that goes into exception, then you can do it by swallowing the exceptions.

```
def validate_side(direction):
    if direction in ('left', 'right'):
        return direction.lower()
    else:
        return None # Note that this else part is not needed as the function will return None in case the if fails; just for readability

a = ['left', 'right', 'up', 'side', 'left']
b = []
for side in a:
    b. append(validate_side(side))
b = filter(None, b) # Removes the empty values
```

For a one-liner,

```
a = ['left', 'right', 'up', 'side', 'left']
b = map(side.lower, filter(validate_side, a))
# This even though small, I would not recommend it;
# Not because it is bad practice; just that bad readability in my opinion
```

Or if you definitely want exceptions in place of sides that are not left or write because it is the requirement and you cannot do anything, you can return exception object in the `validate_side` and save it for whatever purpose(which I cannot think of a use case)

```
def validate_side(direction):
    if direction in ('left', 'right'):
        return direction.lower()
    else:
        return Exception('Wrong side %s is given' % (direction))
```